# Why do we need per-CPU schedulers and separate their context from that of the process's kernel threads?

Tags: operating-system, scheduler, interrupt, multicore

The xv6 (a teaching os kernel developed at MIT) kernel's documentation states, 'Every xv6 process has its own kernel stack and register set. Each CPU has a separate scheduler thread for use when it is executing the scheduler rather than any process’s kernel thread.' However, why do we need per-CPU schedulers and separate their context from that of the process's kernel threads?

It seems to be a good idea in systems with distributed per-core process tables, in which case you wouldn’t want any core to wake up and continue running a process's kernel thread that was in the middle of traversing/ modifying the process table of another core. However, I don’t understand how this helps in xv6, where there is only one process table shared by all cores. Also, enabling interrupts within the scheduler, which has a stack set up during boot time with limited space, could risk overflowing the stack. Is it advisable to completely disable timer interrupts while inside the scheduler?

Comment: Having each core decide for itself what to run next is generally good, rather than having one core run a "master control program" that has to communicate across cores to tell them what to run.  You waste less time making scheduling decisions if your `schedule()` function is a distributed algorithm that all cores can be running simultaneously, with a core able to atomically claim a process waiting for a core and start running it.